# Use QML object from another QML file

Tags: qt, qml

Let's say I have the following files:

main.py

```
app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
engine.load("qml/mainMenu.qml")
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

main.qml

```
ApplicationWindow{
    width: 1200
    height: 800
    ...

    CustomObject{...}
```

customobject.qml

```
CustomObject{...}
```

Now as you can see I want to use CustomObject in main.qml. I couldn't find out how to import (or whatever I have to do) both files so I can do that.

Comment: If main.qml is in the same directory as CustomObject, then you don't need to import anything at all. If it's not working, it may be because you need to rename `customobject.qml` to be `CustomObject.qml`. See the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-documents-definetypes.html#defining-an-object-type-with-a-qml-file).

Comment: Thank you! That was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Great, then I'll write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If main.qml is in the same directory as CustomObject, then you don't need to import anything at all. If it's not working, it is because you need to rename customobject.qml to be CustomObject.qml. See the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-documents-definetypes.html#defining-an-object-type-with-a-qml-file). At least the first letter must be upper-case, and the object's name becomes the same as the filename. (This can actually be overridden in a `qmldir` file though).